# Exclude kotlin.Result from Autocomplete and auto import in Intellij Idea

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

I tried excluding kotlin.Result from the auto complete list but it doesn't work even after invalidating the cache. It works for normal classes.

I followed this official guide https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#configure-code-completion

Is there any way to fix this ?

[image: Exclude settings screenshot]

[image: Autocompletion]

Answer (score 2):

There is a little mismatch in the feature design: [KT-29043](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-29043). Please, vote it. We will try to fix it in near releases.